# Float object not iterable on assignment

Tags: python-2.7

I keep getting this error when running this python file. It occurs on this line:

> p1x, p1y = newList[0]
>   TypeError: 'Float' object is not iterable

Here is the code:

```
newList = []
for i, val in enumerate(poly):      
    if poly[i] != True:
        newList.append(poly[i][0])
n = len(newList)
inside =False
p1x, p1y = newList[0]
for i in range(n+1):
    p2x, p2y = newList[i % n]
    if y > min(p1y,p2y):
        if y <= max(p1y,p2y):
            if x <= max(p1x,p2x):
                if p1y != p2y:
                    xinters = (y-p1y)*(p2x-p1x)/(p2y-p1y)+p1x
                if p1x == p2x or x <= xinters:
                    return True
    p1x,p1y = p2x,p2y

return inside
```

Why is it that when I do this

```
p1x = newList[0]
p1y = newList[0]
```

it works, but not the other way around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is newList[0]?
If it is a single float value, it will give you an error.

newList[0] would have to be a tuple, like (1, 2), to iterate over it.

You could do (If newList[0] and newList[1] are single values.):

```
p1x, p1y = newList[0], newList[1]
```

or

```
newList[0] = (1,2)
p1x, p1y = newList[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `newList[0]` is a `Float`, so it can't be broken into two pieces (as your original code attempts).  Your 2nd attempt is assigning the *same* `Float` to each of `p1x` and `p1y`, which is probably not what you want to do; but if it *is*, then you could write `p1x,p1y = newList[0], newList[0]`.